# How do you pass a dynamic variable into ember-power-select?

Tags: ember.js

I've managed to solve this by using the array being looped on however would like to leave that array untouched.

```
{{#each notes as |note index|}}
  {{#power-select
    selected=note.selectedDropdown
    ...
    |name|
  }}
    {{name}}
  {{/power-select}}
{{/each}}
```

Ideally, I'd like to do something like this

```
{{#each notes as |note index|}}
  {{#power-select
    selected=(concat 'selectedDropdown-' index)
    ...
    |name|
  }}
    {{name}}
  {{/power-select}}
{{/each}}
```

Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: I doubt it is possible in such a way. I recommend putting that select in an component, there you can easily manipulate the `selected` property.

Comment: but why do you need it that way anyway?

Comment: The `notes` are being sent into different components, and I would like to encapsulate this behaviour within this one component.  Setting the property on the note itself leaks this information to the other components and could possibly conflict if they need to do the same.